# window.location.href gets executed immediately on click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsp, firefox, window.location

```
function refresh(context) {
    console.log(" in refresh view ");
    window.location.href = context + '/abc.do';
}
function resetCookie(context) {
    var view = getView();
    if (view == "First") {
        clearCookies();
        setCookie("Second", "on");
        console.log(" context in resetCookie 2");
    } else {
        clearCookies();
        setFirstViewCookie();
        setCookie("First", "on");
        console.log(" context in resetCookie 3");
    }
    console.log(" context in resetCookie 4");
    console.log(" context in resetCookie 5");
    refresh(context);
    return false;
}
```

```html
<td>
    <span id="firstview" style="display:none;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=" resetCookie('<%= request.getContextPath()%>')">secondview</a>
    </span>
    <span id="secondview" style="display:none;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resetCookie('<%= request.getContextPath()%>')">firstview</a>
    </span>
</td>
```

This piece of code works fine in IE. But, in chrome and firefox as soon as I click on the a tag, somehow `window.location.href` gets called first and so *page refresh happens without executing the code inside function*. I have checked this by removing `location.href` line and I see that all lines get executed in sequence, also I checked the line number from which refresh call happens in networks tab - *it shows this very line number* inside refresh function, *it doesn't even print console.log(" in refresh view "); statement inside refresh function*.

Ideally, everything inside resetCookie should happen and then `window.location.href` inside refresh should happen.

This is `spring tags jsp`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this 21st century version will help

```js
var context = "<%= request.getContextPath()%>";

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("reset")].forEach(lnk => {
    lnk.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
      const id = this.id;
      clearCookies();
      setCookie(id, "on");
      this.href = context + '/abc.do';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none }
```

```html
<a id="First" class="reset"  href="#">secondview</a></span>
<a id="Second" class="reset" href="#">firstview</a></span>
```

Comment: Definitely, that is the way. But after lot of debugging , I figured out that my cookie code was never being hit because though I am setting httpOnly as false from client side, when the rest call hits and comes back to GUI, all the cookies from request are made httpOnly true, due to changes made in the backend - which is making that particular cookie unreadable and front end code flow affected. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very into `spring` and `jsp` but I can guess that `clearCookies();` or/and `setCookie();` methods run async operations.
Because of javascript's single threaded architecture you get called `refresh()` before previous methods are completed.

Comment: Your reply made me dig into cookies behaviors, and somehow led to finding the solution. After a lot of debugging , I figured out that my cookie code was never being hit because though I am setting httpOnly as false from client side, when the rest call hits and comes back to GUI, all the cookies from request are made httpOnly true, due to changes made in the backend - which is making that particular cookie unreadable and front end code flow affected.

Comment: Great! Glad that I could navigate you to right direction